# RtlCaptureStackBackTrace is capturing no frame

Tags: c++, c, windows, driver, windows-kernel

I am using RtlCaptureStackBackTrace in my kernel mode driver and trying to get the call trace, but it is capturing zero frames. Code is :

```
PVOID *stackTrace = NULL;
PULONG traceHash = NULL;
USHORT capturedFrames = 0;

capturedFrames = RtlCaptureStackBackTrace(0, 10, stackTrace, traceHash);
```

when i check stacktrace, it is NULL.

Comment: Formatted code example

Answer (score 0):

you provide `stackTrace` as `NULL` but according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-rtlcapturestackbacktrace):

> Caller-allocated array in which pointers to the return addresses
>   captured from the current stack trace are returned.

this means that you need to allocate an array for the `BackTrace` Parameter.

For Example:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10
PVOID stackTrace[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0};
USHORT capturedFrames = 0;

capturedFrames = RtlCaptureStackBackTrace(0, ARRAY_SIZE, stackTrace, NULL);
```

Note: don't use it in production code, it is better if you use dynamic allocation using `ExAllocatePoolWithTag()`)

Also look at this Microsoft [Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/storage/class/classpnp/src/debug.c)

Comment: Oh! sorry, my bad, i didn't notice, This worked for me, Thanks but only issue is now I want to capture almost 5 to 6 traces back in kernel, like if I have API1()->API2->...->API6() so If i traverse back to get API1 address from API6() then it should give, but it is only capturing 2 frames at max, is there any better way in kernel for capturing back traces?